# Why doesn't AuthorizationCodeGrantBuilder provide a way to set accessTokenResponseClient?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I can see that each authorization grant type follows a process, that is, there will be an implementation of **OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient** to complete the access token acquisition operation. In fact, the authorization code flow also provides **DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient**, but why not let users set it in **AuthorizationCodeGrantBuilder**?

In this way, some logic processing can be added uniformly when defining **OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager**, instead of being scattered in multiple places.
Now the settings are done here **org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer. TokenEndpointConfig#accessTokenResponseClient**.

I would like to know, what is the purpose of this? Do you have relevant documents or explanations, please help to provide them, thank you!